# Writing an iteration using two functions

Tags: programming, iterators

I have been given two functions with an initial condition. One function becomes the variable of the other. I need to run the program for 10 iterations.

```
d = 100 (initial condition)
x = (300*d)/(d + 100)
```

Next

```
d1 = 200 - x
```

`d1` should become the variable of the function `x` instead of `d`.

Again

```
 x2 = (300*d1)/(d1 + 100)
 d2 = 200 - x2
 x3 = (300*d2)/(d2 + 100)
 d3 = 200 - x3
```

and repeat the process until 10 iterations have been made.

How can I write a program to carry out this process?

Comment: `NestList[200 - 300 #/(# + 100) &, 100, 10]`

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LoopingConstructs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[y_, x_] := {200 - x, 300 y/(y + 100)}
ic = {100, 150}
nf[n_] := NestList[f @@ # &, ic, n]
TableForm[nf[10], TableHeadings -> {Range[0, 10], {"d", "x"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. it helps a lot. I really needed to display it as a table too. Thank you once again.

Comment: My goodness:  Isn't that *my* solution (below)?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I am sorry I did not see your solutions. I agree that they use the same strategy. However your use of null rather than the value of the initial x renders your output difficult to interpret. This, I agree, is a trivial difference but I can only express that it was unintentional. I suggest that you raise with OP. I will completely accept change in vote etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
f1 = Function[d, 300*d/(d + 100)]  (* your first transformation *)
f2 = Function[x, 200 - x]  (* your second transformation *)
f = f2@*f1  (* your composed transformation *)
(* using NestList *)
NestList[f, 100, 10]
(* using RecurrenceTable *)
RecurrenceTable[{d[n + 1] == f[d[n]], d[0] == 100}, d, {n, 0, 10}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's do two simple pre-computations.

```
With[{d = 200 - x}, (300 d)/(d + 100)]
```

> `(300 (200 - x))/(300 - x)`

and

```
With[{d = 100}, (300 d)/(d + 100)]
```

> `150`

Then the iteration can be written as

```
NestList[300 (200 - #)/(300 - #) &, 150, 10]
```

> `{150, 100, 150, 100, 150, 100, 150, 100, 150, 100, 150}`

Answer (score 3):

One could compose the two component function, but another trick is to compute {f1[x], f2[f1[x]}, then take the second component and feed it back as the new `x`:

```
Flatten@NestList[
   {temp = 300 #[[2]]/(#[[2]] + 100), 200 - temp} &, 
   {Null, 100}, 10]
```

(*

{Null, 100, 150, 50, 100, 100, 150, 50, 100, 100, 150, 50, 100, 100,
150, 50, 100, 100, 150, 50, 100, 100}

*)

I note that I get a different sequence than @corey979.

Comment: Yes sequence is little bit different. But thanks a lot for the help.